# android facebook permission friends

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem with permission on android Facebook sdk. When I use login button for authorise and getting friend all went right.

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

and I get permission.

But when I use Session, I can't get access to friends:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SignUpActivity.this).setPermissions("user_friends", "public_profile").setCallback(SignUpActivity.this));
} else {
    Session.openActiveSession(SignUpActivity.this, true, SignUpActivity.this);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I get access to get friends in app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. I must create new session. I must use this code:

```
 Session session = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"), this);
```

instead of

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

It's fix my problem.